# how do i automatically back up my sql server database every month?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a sql server 2005 database without around 100 tables. i need to back it up every month. is there a way to automate this process? how would i do it? i am a newbie so please explain thoroughly

if it is a stored procedure please let me know what that procedure would look like and where to call it from.

Comment: Since you're a newbie, I'd suggest starting here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx

Comment: Why do you only want to backup once a month? Are you prepared to lose one month's worth of data?

Comment: what version of SQL 2005?

Comment: The version is SQL 2005, we need to know what edition it is.

Comment: Every month? Don't you mean every day? Or don't you value that data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you could create a maintenance plan to do the backups and then you would schedule it to run once a month. See here: http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/sql-server-maintenance-plan.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create a scheduled task and call the SQL method. Think about using a VB script or so. I did this for backing up a SQL server to a zip-drive every day and it worked great.

Comment: please show me how

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a database script and a scheduled task.  Visit [this link](http://www.brianmadden.com/blogs/guestbloggers/archive/2007/05/07/how-to-automate-the-backup-of-a-sql-server-2005-express-data-store.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122690/what-is-a-simple-command-line-program-or-script-to-backup-sql-server-databases)

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Express you can't use Maintenance Plans, you'll need something like http://expressmaint.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VB Script I wrote exactly for this purpose:
https://github.com/ezrarieben/mssql-backup-vbs/

Schedule a task in the "Task Scheduler" to execute the script as you like and it'll backup the entire DB to a BAK file and save it wherever you specify.